# Android walkie talkie application unable to connect to server

Tags: android, server, mjsip

I am trying to modify an open source application Android Walkie Talkie http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-ptt/ but the original application itself seems to have problem while connecting to server. I could not find the problem. the application is using mjsip server, it is showing getaddrinfo(-1) error=8.

Comment: you won't be able to get any help unless you provide more information. Tell us what error you get, or simply contact the developers of that project.

Comment: in application log its showing getaddrinfo(-1) error=4